# Does UML have an universal standard way?

Tags: uml

I'm completely new at UML, and I barely know how it really works.

The point is: Does it have a standard way to do or project stuffs? If I'm trying to do a class diagram, or show a complex connection with a DB, the draws need to follow a rule?

Like if I'm doing the draw at a software with their owns figures. If I'm going to change the UML's software, the figures  would must be the same?

Answer (score 3):

No. UML is a language. Like you would not say English has a standard way to write a novel, there is no standard way for UML to describe projects.

However, a couple of methodologies have evolved based on UML. It's hard to tell the right one and it will differ from case to case. For me the ICONIX approach did work very well and I guess that for a beginner this is the best way to find his way to a methodology. For large scale enterprise architecture you would rather look into TOGAF and all those military based ones. But that should be the next step after a couple of other intermediate ones.